# Handling end of SSH session by remote server in Expect script

Tags: expect

I made 2 Expect scripts to SSH to a list of servers and change passwords. One for AIX and one for RedHat Linux.

The AIX script is working fine, but the Linux script is giving me a problem. The reason is that on the Linux servers, when you are forced to change an expired password, after the password is changed the remote side kills the SSH session.

```
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
Connection to drm23rdv closed.
send: spawn id exp20 not open
while executing...
```

At this point the script stops completely and there are still lots of servers to log in to. (and the current password is just a temporary one, although I could modify the script to use my permanent password choice but I like to do that as root)

What I would like to do after the initial, forced password change is log back into the server and change the password again as root. I am pretty sure I can handle that, but first I need to figure out a way to have expect handle the closed SSH session with more dignity than just giving up.

Comment: Why can't you expect the "Connection to xxxxx closed" string, and then spawn a new session? That should be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `expect eof {do something}`, or the connection might close at any time, use `expect_before {eof {do something}}`